# Show that no integer of the form $a^3 +1$ is a prime for $a>1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, problem-solving

Can someone please solve this and explain the steps taken to reach this solution ?

Comment: $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$

Comment: In general, you have the following factorization for all odd $n$: $x^n+y^n=(x+y)(x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}y + x^{n-3}y^2-\ldots - xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$. It's a nifty thing to remember.

Comment: Dudes, this was handled 5 years ago and multiple times in between. In fact back in the day it was deemed only worth a link. Downvotes to all but the honest commenters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factorise $$a^3 +1 \equiv (a+1)(a^2 -a +1)$$

This is made up of the product of two integers if $a > 1$, namely $a+1$ and $a^2 -a + 1$. i.e: it is the very definition of a composite number. (that is, unless $a+1$ or $a^2 - a  + 1$ is equal to $1$, but the hypothesis $a>1$ immediately gives you that.

In fact, it's normally a good idea to factorise $$a^n + b^n = (a+b)(a^{n-1} - a^{n-2}b - \cdots - ab^{n-2} + b^{n-1})$$

in these sort of situations.

Comment: how do you know it is not prime ?

Comment: Added a bit to my answer to help explain.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $a^3+1=(a+1)(a^2-a+1)$, so...